# The message_read event doesn’t fire from the Facebook Messenger plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I’ve programmed my bot to ask a series of questions based on the message_read event (once a user has read the message, the next one will send). However, the Customer Chat Plugin (beta) doesn’t seem to be firing this event.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in the plugin yet.